# Handling Exception like validation errors in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I have configured the **SimpleMappingExceptionResolver** in my web application, which is handling all the *unexpected* exceptions in the application and directing the user a to simple error page for recovery.

But what would be a best practice of handling an *expected* exception *(more specifically: exception caused by hibernate optimistic concurrency control)*?

I don't want the user to be directed to a new error page, but allow him/her to continue working in the same jsp page. What is the best method to achieve this?

Comment: swallow the exception where they can occur (maybe log and give a warning on the same jsp page) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming Spring 3, you can annotate methods on your Controller class with [@ExceptionHandler](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ExceptionHandler.html) to define what should happen when particular types of exceptions come out of your handler methods.  The signature is not quite as flexible as @RequestMapping methods, but you can generally manage what you want.  (Which in this case sounds like just add an error message to the model map and re-run the method that handles GET)

Comment: Just be mindful that you don't have an implicit map, if you have methods annotated with @ModelAttribute that you're using to populate it, you may need to manually rerun them depending on the View!